# Can I insert tag(search tag) in command line of vim?

Tags: vim

I had read `expand` usage, but it doesn't provide such function.

For example, My `tags` file contain those contents:

```
ACTION  action/action.h /^}ACTION,*LPACTION;$/;"    t   line:169
typeref:struct:__anon14
ACTIONDATA  action/action.h /^} ACTIONDATA,*LPACTIONDATA;$/;"   t   line:327
typeref:struct:tagActionData
ADJ_RANGE   elo_touch/igslib_elo_touch.cpp  6;" d   line:6  file:
ADJ_RANGE   micro_touch/igslib_micro_touch.cpp  7;" d   line:7  file:
```

So when I type `ADJ` and enter shortcut with `<c-x><c-]>`, vim will complete `ADJ_RANGE` for me.
But **that feature doesn't supported in command line**. That's the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It’s (at least to me) not quite clear what you’re trying to do. Can you expand on the title of the question and maybe give an example?

Comment: I'd add an example just now. Sorry for poor explanation.

Comment: Am I interpreting your question properly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where I found this but if you have bash completion installed this solution should work.

Put the following into `~/.bash_completion`

```
_vim_ctags() {
    local cur prev

        COMPREPLY=()
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    case "${prev}" in
        -t)
            # Avoid the complaint message when no tags file exists
            if [ ! -r ./tags ]
            then
                return
            fi

            # Escape slashes to avoid confusing awk
            cur=${cur////\\/}

            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "`awk -v ORS=" "  "/^${cur}/ { print \\$1 }" tags`" ) )
            ;;
        *)
            # Perform usual completion mode
            ;;
        esac
}

# Files matching this pattern are excluded
excludelist='*.@(o|O|so|SO|so.!(conf)|SO.!(CONF)|a|A|rpm|RPM|deb|DEB|gif|GIF|jp?(e)g|JP?(E)G|mp3|MP3|mp?(e)g|MP?(E)G|avi|AVI|asf|ASF|ogg|OGG|class|CLASS)'

complete -F _vim_ctags -f -X "${excludelist}" vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview
```

This should be sourced automatically when the shell launches if bash completion is set up properly. After this is set up you can use

```
vim -t ADJ<Tab>
```

to auto complete the tags found in the current directory. When you run vim with the `-t` command line flag vim will open to that tag.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is not what the asker wants/needs but this is something that'll be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, he is. He totally misunderstands my question‧

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command-line window.  Here are a few excerpts from `:help cmdline-window`:

```
In the command-line window the command line can be edited just like editing
text in any window.  It is a special kind of window, because you cannot leave
it in a normal way.
...
There are two ways to open the command-line window:
1. From Command-line mode, use the key specified with the 'cedit' option.
   The default is CTRL-F when 'compatible' is not set.
2. From Normal mode, use the "q:", "q/" or "q?" command.
...
You can now use commands to move around and edit the text in the window.  Both
in Normal mode and Insert mode.
...
There are several ways to leave the command-line window:

<CR>                Execute the command-line under the cursor.  Works both in
            Insert and in Normal mode.
```

So you can open a command-line window, edit a line as much as you like, including using `<C-X><C-]>` for tag completion, and then execute the command when you are done.

Comment: Yeah, you got the point. Although that isn't the one -shot answer, but it still a workground one. :)

Comment: Give it a try:  you may like it.  For a long time, I just quit the command-line window any time I accidentally hit `q:`, but now I use it on purpose from time to time.